# Can int store the base address of string in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Why do the code run without error ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
    int i="string"; //the base of string can be stored in a character pointer 
    printf("%s\n",i);
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

//compiling on ideone.com language c

OUTPUT:

string

134513984 //some garbage(address of "string")

Please explain if there is some flexibility in the pointer in c. I tried it for c++ which gives error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘int*’ in initialization

Comment: C is a lenient language that puts much power and responsibly into the hands of programmer.  If you want to do something crazy (like this), you can!

Comment: Your warning for C++ is because string literals are of type `const char []` in C++, but of type `char []` in C (although you must not modify them, even in C).

Comment: @mafso: No, that's not the reason. Firstly, in C++ it actually reports an *error*, not a warning. Secondly, while what you are saying about the actual types is true, the code is broken in both C and C++ for identical reasons and `const` has nothing to do with it. The text of the diagnostic message will differ between the languages, but both must inform the user about the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot assume this in general. In part, this is because `int` may not be the same size as `char *` (in fact, on many 64-bit compilers it will *not* be the same size).

If you want to store a pointer as an integer, the appropriate type to use is actually `intptr_t`, from `<stdint.h>`. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer's value.

However, the circumstances when you'd actually want to do this are somewhat rare, and when you do do this you should also include an explicit cast:

```
intptr_t i=(intptr_t)"string"; //the base of string can be stored in a character pointer
```

This also complicates printing its value, you'll need to use a macro to be portable:

```
printf("%"PRIiPTR,i);
```

To print the original string, you should also cast:

```
printf("%s", (char *)i);
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, no: the C standard states that conversions from pointers to integers are implementation defined. Further, this can be problematic on systems where `sizeof(char *)` and `sizeof(int)` are different (i.e. x86-64), for two reasons:

1. `int i = "string";` can lose information, if the e.g. 64-bit pointer cannot fit in a 32-bit integer.
2. `printf` expects a pointer to be passed in, but gets a smaller integer. It winds up reading some garbage into the full pointer, and can crash your code (or worse).

Often times, however, compilers are "smart" enough to "fix" arguments to `printf`. Further, you seem to be running on a platform where pointers and integers *are* the same size, so you got lucky.

Answer (score 1):

If you compiled this program with warnings (which you should) you'd get the following complaints:

```
main.c:3:9: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'char [7]' [-Wint-conversion]
    int i="string"; //the base of string can be stored in a character pointer 
        ^ ~~~~~~~~
main.c:4:19: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("%s\n",i);
            ~~    ^
            %d
2 warnings generated.
```

Warnings generally mean you're doing something that could cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Most C compilers will let you do this, but that doesn't make it a good idea.  Here, the address of the character array `"string"` gets stored in `i`.  The `printf` options are determining how the integer is interpreted (as an address or an integer).  This can be problematic when `char*` is not the same size as an `int` (e.g. on most 64 bit machines).

The C++ compiler is more picky and won't let you compile code like this. C compilers are much more willing, although they will usually generate warnings letting the programmer know it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ill-formed in both C and C++. It is illegal to do

```
int i = "string";
```

in both languages. In both languages conversion from a pointer to an integer requires an explicit cast.

The only reason your C compiler accepted it is that it was configured by default for rather loose error checking. (A rather typical situation with C compilers.) Tighten up your C compiler settings and it should issue an error for the above initialization. I.e. you can use an explicit conversion

```
int i = (int) "string";
```

with implementation-dependent results, but you can't legally do it implicitly.

In any case, the warning your compiler emitted for the above initialization is already a sufficient form of a diagnostic message for this violation.

Comment: It runs on ideone and codeblocks without error, but shows a warning in CodeBlocks.

Comment: @kkr_manit: As I said, in default mode this code is typically accepted by C compilers. However, a diagnostic message is required in any case. If the compilers behind ideone or codeblocks (GCC) compile this without any diagnostic messages, those compilers are broken. It is more likely that ideone deliberately suppresses such messages, since GCC in default mode definitely warns about the problem.